# Mappings in aws cloudformation. Fn::FindInMap object requires three parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have mappings section:

```
Mappings:
  ScheduledPeriodMap:
    Development:
      "Expression": "cron(0 12 30 2 ? *)"
    Production:
      "Expression": "rate(1 minute)"
```

An later I use it:

```
Events:
  ScheduleMyLambda:
    Type: Schedule
    Properties:
      Schedule: !FindInMap [ScheduledPeriodMap, !Sub "${Environment}", "Expression"]
```

I get exception during `cloudformation deploy`:

> Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason:
>   Template error: every Fn::FindInMap object requires three parameters,
>   the map name, map key and the attribute for return value

What is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [Fn::FindInMap documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html) is written:

> Supported Functions You can use the following functions in a
>   Fn::FindInMap function:
>
> Fn::FindInMap
>
> Ref

it means you can not use `!Sub "${Environment}"` here, please use `!Ref Environment` instead.

Comment: thank you. it would be really nice if sam build actually exposed some of these things opposed to having to wait for me to build and then deploy which takes forever just to tell me there was a syntax error in my template...

Answer (score 0):

For those who come here from google like I did, now some functions are supported in `Fn:FindInMap` with `Transform: 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'`.

See docs here [Fn::FindInMap enhancements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap-enhancements.html)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34366582)